# .gif file will not fit in bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the Bootstrap grid system to organise objects because I need to ensure the site is mobile-friendly. All objects adjust well to the resolution of the screen except for 1 gif.

On full resolution screen, the gif is 500x500 pixels and is perfectly sized to fit with the rest of the screen. However, on mobile (all devices), it remains 500x500, even when this makes it larger than the screen. Interestingly, on iPad pro (not other iPad) it assumes a width of 102.4 pixels, retaining height of 500.

All other items adjust perfectly and stay inside the viewport.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
            maximum-scale=1">
        <link 
            href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
            rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <style>
        html {
            max-height: 100%;
            max-width: 100%;
        }
       .logo {
         color: #000000;
         box-sizing: border-box;
         object-fit: cover;
         max-width: 10vw;
         overflow: hidden;
       }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    [class*="col-"] {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 700px;
    }
  }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-7 name">
                <p>text</p>
              </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 logo">
               <img src="./cubegif.gif" class="image.fluid" alt="logo">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am considering if the predefined size of the .gif is overriding whatever I am doing, but that does not explain the change on ipad pro.

Comment: use `img-responsive` class in gif and try to make `font-size` small in mobile screen using media query...

Comment: thank you for this, both excellent ideas. I tried both but unfortunately, they generated no change. I have no idea why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to find an answer! Posted below n case anyone else finds this thread and has the same problem:

in the HTML img tag, I gave it the following class:

```
<img class="fixed-ratio-resize" src="./cubegif.gif" alt="logo">
```

and added the following CSS:

```
 `.fixed-ratio-resize {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9;
  }`
```

I found this solution on http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/entry.php?293-3-Ways-to-Resize-Scale-Web-Images-in-Responsive-Design

Many thanks for all contributions!

Answer (score 1):

Some quotation marks were missing in your code?

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-7 title">
                <p>text text text text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-5 logo">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```